# How should I proceed to solve this error on an Android Project?

Tags: android, build.gradle

I have a project from an Android app in Android Studio(Electric Eel), it was working fine last time I used it but now I get this error.

*Unsupported Java.
Your build is currently configured to use Java 17 and Gradle 5.6.4.
Possible solution:

- Upgrade Gradle wrapper to 7.2 version and re-import the project*

I tried several things from like the 3 last days and now I deleted all and recovered a backup from another disk to start again.

I don't understand if on the Gradle part is enough to change the Gradle version from the UI settings or if do I need to change something in the code.

Also, I don't understand how to "re-import" the project. I now how to open. What should I do to "re-import" it?

Currently I can't see the layout until a successful sync.

This is what I get after Gradle update.

[image: Error after Gradle Update]

This is build.gradle(Module:App)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        MyRemoto {
            keyAlias 'key0'
            keyPassword 'pass'
            storeFile file('D:/Extras/My_Remoto_sin_SMS/keystoreSinSms.jks')
            storePassword 'storePass'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "MyRemote.alarmas.Myalarmas"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 33 //D:\Android_My\My_Remote_sin_SMS\keystoreSinSms.jks
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.6.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.MyRemoto
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:+'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

I'm not using Kotling, Should I delete this?

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

I deleted it and solved a lot of errors.

Here the gradle-wrapper file

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Comment: Did you updated Gradle and it still didn't work?  Please add your `build.gradle`  from **app module** and check which version of gradle is being used in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file (inside of **gradle/wrapper**)

Comment: @ThalesIsidoro Yes, and get 42 errors in MainActivity.java - Starting with **import androidx.annotation.NonNull; import android.support.*;**(Cannot resolve symbol)

Comment: @ThalesIsidoro I just added a picture and some code. Do you need something else to figure out what is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I need everything you have on `build.gradle`, and I need to see if you're really using a new Gradle version in `gradle-wrapper.properties`, so please add this file too.

Comment: My guess for now is the incompatibility of dependencies, as apparently your build structure is from a very old project and you're using a very outdated version of dependencies, like `appcompat 1.0.0` and `material 1.0.0`, both from 2018... and that's a bad sign. Anyway, I need the information I asked you in comment above to confirm.

Comment: @ThalesIsidoro You are right is an old App. I just added the full code of build.gradle file.